# How Push Notification Service Works for iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod-touch

I am developing an app using push notification service for both iPhone and iPod Touch. For iPhone the user can register their device using UDID or phone number. How can an iPod touch people receive the notifications as there is no phone number for the device?

I must miss something from my understanding. Please help!

Thanks.
Marcelo

Answer (score 2):

The phone number is not needed. You register with methods built into the sdk and receive back a token.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

The iPod touch will only receive notifications when it's connected via Wifi.

In any case, remember only the last notification will be sent if the device is not available when notifications are sent out.

-t